How to write a file DIRECTLY to tape with dd
I am trying to write a file directly to a tape in my LTO4 tape drive. From what I understand, this should be possible.
However, when I attempt to use dd to write to it (e.g. dd if="/test.img" of=/dev/nst0 bs=1024) it fails. From what I understand from the output, this is because I am not using tar?
dd: error reading '/dev/nst0': Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00600797 s, 0.0 kB/s
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Is tar absolutely necessary to write to a tape? If not, what am I doing wrong?
The image itself is simply a disk image. Nothing special.
Tape drive information:
Product Type: Tape Drive
Vendor ID: 'HP      '
Product ID: 'Ultrium 4-SCSI  '
Revision: 'A63Z'

If you need any more information, please let me know.

When you tell us you run a command, and run some entirely different command it's difficult to help...

I understand. I should have checked before I posted. I plan to mark as answered as soon as the website will let me.

I made a stupid mistake. The script I was using has many modes, and I forgot to change the mode for writing to the appropriate setting. So it was attempting to read a tar archive instead.
Whoops!
